# How can I get a cone shape of arbitrary size in an hex board?

Tags: algorithm, hexagonal-grid

I'm implementing engine tools for my hex board game and this one is becoming messy. I want to get a list of all the positions that a cone of size N would have, given "caster" origin X,Y and origin in X0, Y0 taking direction into account. So far I have been able to get a size one cone using a "simple pattern" approach, but it doesn't translate well for N-sized cones.

This is the original cone

[image]

and the code

```
public PositionArray getArcAdjacents(int originx, int originy, int targetx, int targety,
        int range) {
    final FloatPair direction = this.getDirectionVector(originx, originy, targetx, targety);
    final PositionArray highlights = new PositionArray(gameMap);
    highlights.add(new Pair(targetx, targety));
    int offset = 0;
    if ((targetx % 2) == 0) {
        offset = 1;
    }
    if (direction.x > 0) {
        if (direction.y >= 0) {
            highlights.add(new Pair(targetx - 1, (targety + 1) - offset));
            highlights.add(new Pair(targetx, targety - 1));
        } else {
            highlights.add(new Pair(targetx, targety + 1));
            highlights.add(new Pair(targetx - 1, targety - offset));
        }
    } else if (direction.x < 0) {
        if (direction.y >= 0) {
            highlights.add(new Pair(targetx + 1, (targety + 1) - offset));
            highlights.add(new Pair(targetx, targety - 1));
        } else {
            highlights.add(new Pair(targetx + 1, targety - offset));
            highlights.add(new Pair(targetx, targety + 1));
        }
    } else {
        if (direction.y > 0) {
            highlights.add(new Pair(targetx + 1, targety - offset));
            highlights.add(new Pair(targetx - 1, targety - offset));
        } else if (direction.y < 0) {
            highlights.add(new Pair(targetx + 1, (targety + 1) - offset));
            highlights.add(new Pair(targetx - 1, (targety + 1) - offset));
        }
    }
    return highlights;
}
```

Comment: What type of coord system are you using?

Comment: Odd-q with 0,0 on the bottom left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could fix it with a bit of algorithmics:

```
public PositionArray getArcRange(int originx, int originy, int targetx, int targety, int range) {
    if (range < 0) {
        range = 0;
    }
    final PositionArray open = new PositionArray(gameMap);
    final PositionArray closed = new PositionArray(gameMap);
    final FloatPair direction = this.getDirectionVector(targetx, targety, originx, originy);
    closed.add(new Pair(targetx, targety));
    while (closed.size > 0) {
        final Pair position = closed.removeIndex(0);
        if (!open.contains(position, false)
                && (this.getDistance(targetx, targety, position.x, position.y) <= range)) {
            closed.addAll(this.getArcAdjacents(position, direction));
            open.add(position);
        }
    }
    open.removeIndex(0);
    return open;
}

private PositionArray getArcAdjacents(Pair target, FloatPair direction) {
    final PositionArray highlights = new PositionArray(gameMap);
    int offset = 0;
    if ((target.x % 2) == 0) {
        offset = 1;
    }
    if (direction.x > 0) {
        if (direction.y >= 0) {
            highlights.add(new Pair(target.x - 1, (target.y + 1) - offset));
            highlights.add(new Pair(target.x, target.y - 1));
        } else {
            highlights.add(new Pair(target.x, target.y + 1));
            highlights.add(new Pair(target.x - 1, target.y - offset));
        }
    } else if (direction.x < 0) {
        if (direction.y >= 0) {
            highlights.add(new Pair(target.x + 1, (target.y + 1) - offset));
            highlights.add(new Pair(target.x, target.y - 1));
        } else {
            highlights.add(new Pair(target.x + 1, target.y - offset));
            highlights.add(new Pair(target.x, target.y + 1));
        }
    } else {
        if (direction.y > 0) {
            highlights.add(new Pair(target.x + 1, target.y - offset));
            highlights.add(new Pair(target.x - 1, target.y - offset));
        } else if (direction.y < 0) {
            highlights.add(new Pair(target.x + 1, (target.y + 1) - offset));
            highlights.add(new Pair(target.x - 1, (target.y + 1) - offset));
        }
    }
    return highlights;
}
```

Result: 
[image: Cones!]

**Beware of the trap, my PositionArray doesn't allow duplicates or positions outside the board.**